# Use initrd as root filesystem for network boot

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-panic, pxe

I'm creating a stand-alone set of netboot images based on a LinuxFromScratch installation (7.0, kernel 3.1.0). I want to deploy that image to many diskless clients, but NFS is in my situation not an option. The root filesystem has been trimmed down to an ext2 image of 350mb uncompressed (with 7% free space included).

I tried to boot the kernel over the network using PXELINUX, by passing the root filesystem (root.img) as initrd using this PXELINUX config:

```
label pxeboot
  kernel /bzImage
  append rw root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=512000 initrd=/root.img
```

However, linux panics with "no filesystem could mount root, tried:  ext3 ext2 iso9660 udf".
This is the closest I could get, if I change the `root=` parameter, I get a panic telling me that it couldn't find a root device. (no filesystem sounds closer to my goal than no device).

My question is now: where do I start looking to solve this - I think I misconfigured the kernel image, but I do not know which settings I could alter to make this work.

Comment: have you go inird and ramdisk support enabled in kernel?

Comment: yes, I compiled it into the kernel...

Comment: 350mb seem to be a lot for tftp: are you able to verify that initrd file is transferred properly. E.g. by checking the tftpd log?